# How to debug node,js app in docker container and nodemon?

Tags: node.js, docker, debugging

Im trying to debug my node.js app. I tried to connect with my container app using webstorm and Chrome Node.js V8 --inspector Manager (NiM). In  the both cases I couldn't connect to my container app :(

I run 2 containers in a docker network "DockerNetwork"
Ngrok:

```
docker run --rm -it --network DockerNetwork wernight/ngrok ngrok http myAction:5000
```

docker run -v //:/action -it --rm --network DockerNetwork --name myAction myImage

My docker environment looks like that:
[image]

my dockerFile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN mkdir -p /action
WORKDIR /
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
VOLUME /action/functions/node_modules
EXPOSE 9229
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrpoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /action/functions
npm install
nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 start.js -L
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also add a `-p 9229:9229` to your `docker run` command to actually expose the port?  The `EXPORT` in the Dockerfile doesn't do this automatically.

Comment: I tiried it without success :(

Comment: In windows I put the command docker-machine ip default
I got 192.168.99.100 and it works :) But how to do the same in Windows?

Comment: If this is still relevant, I'd suggest you update your answer with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file. I got it working for myself with WebStorm 2019.1.4
The thing is instead of using Chrome Node.js V8 engine use Attach to Node.js/Chrome with reconnect automatically option ticked.